# How to prevent the script from being canceled when you receive a proxy server error

Tags: python

Can anyone guide me? How can I prevent my script from being completely canceled when I receive a proxy server error?

```
def proxy_on(self, email, password):
    if proxy_on_of == "y":
        #open proxy file
        prox = open(proxy_file, "r").readlines()
        cleaned_prox = [items.rstrip() for items in prox]
        random_proxy = choice(cleaned_prox)

        p_http = {"http": random_proxy,"https": random_proxy}
        p_sock4 = {"http": "socks4://" + random_proxy,"https":"socks4://" + random_proxy}
        p_sock5 = {"http":"socks5://" + random_proxy,"https":"socks5://" + random_proxy}
        #Proxy Type
        if proxy_type == "1":
            proxy = p_http
        elif proxy_type == "2":
            proxy = p_sock4
        elif proxy_type == "3":
            proxy = p_sock5
        #requests ready
    session = requests.session()
    try:
        session.get("https://www.crunchyroll.com", proxies = proxy, timeout = 60)
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError as err:
        print("Proxy Not Working: " + random_proxy)
    else:
        break
```

As you can see, probe with the exception "ProxyError", but the result was null

Comment: What does _probe with the exception "ProxyError"_ mean? What's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your try except in a while loop to continue until the session.get receives an answer and continue the while loop in the except